# resolving a typedef, and namespaces VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, typedef

I am working on making a physics engine (with the help of a book), and the book suggests that I create a namespace for the engine to exist in, and for the first part I declare a 'typedef' for variables like so

```
typedef float real;
```

and I can understand the explanation that the author gives being that "if precision needs change then you can just go to this one line, and change it, and then maybe have to change at most 10 helper functions, and clarity of representation, but I think it coincides with the other two things, so I hope this is follow-able.

the book asks that I define the typedef, and helper functions in one file (to minimize file hopping if change is needed), and then include that before the other files are compiled, and to do all of this in a namespace (I named Physics), then in another file create classes to be used in the engine. though the direct problem is with intellisense, and resolving

```
genFunction.h
namespace Physics{
typedef float real;
}


Classes.h
#include "genFunction.h"
namespace Physics{
class Vector3{
public :
    real x;   // visual studio is throwing that Physics::real is not a type name
    real y;
    real z;
    // VS is not offering collapsing, or any form of 
    // auto/assistance with lines.
    // almost like it does not want me to have classes
    // in my own namespaces
    Vector3(){ // uncolapsable 
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
};
}
```

am I doing anything wrong considering that the compiler is ignoring that I have done a typedef, and it is upscope of where the issue is occurring, and then the fact that VS isn't even showing suggestions while I am inside a class in a self made namespace troubles me slightly.

Edit: primary solution found to resolution of type. apparently instead of a `{` I put a `(` on one of the methods, and that caused it to act like the entire namespace didn't exist. though VS will still not give me any kind of assistance (function/class/namespace collapsing, or completion suggestions even with ctrl+spacebar) also I have some helper functions that I use (self made pow(), sqrt() ) that I use that cause linker errors if not in a class, but this goes away when I put inline on them. is this a bad thing to resolve a linker?

Comment: Have you checked the spelling of the header file ? `"genfunction.h"` or `"genFunction.h"` ?

Comment: this is a generalization, and in my code it is the same. corrected in question

Comment: In that case, the code seems to be [working](http://ideone.com/QBnyK) with gcc. Are you using any older version of MSVC ?

Comment: The code as written here looks fine.  The fact that the IDE doesn't recognize it probably means there's a typo somewhere upstream that isn't (necessarily) illegal itself but is messing up your definitions. First you can try a simple clean-rebuild, sometimes that helps - and if not, you will probably need to post more code. Start by pulling out the relevant bits into a test case on your own machine.  If a minimal example reproduces it, we can help more. If the minimal example does not reproduce it, you are on your way to finding the problem yourself.

Comment: Maybe you already know this (and you left them out intentionally in your code snippets), but you should use *include guards* in your header files (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). This standard practice will save you all kinds of grief as your project becomes larger.

Comment: @EmileCormier thank you for mentioning that I usually start adding them when I start getting multiple file dependencies fileA needs fileB, and so does fileT.

Comment: @gardian06 : It's best to *always* use include guards, no matter what the dependencies are. `FileA.h` may only have another file dependent on it for this project, but maybe it'll have more dependants on another project. Always using include guards will make your header files more future-proof and easier to reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the compiler isn't *throwing* anything.
Since you haven't said otherwise, I'm assuming your code compiles fine. The problem is with Intellisense then, and nothing more.

Intellisense in C++ is notoriously shaky. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doens't. It may depend on the phases of the moon.

Sometimes you can "encourage" it a bit by being more explicit. If you type `::`, it should suggest all the members of the global namespace. `::Physics::` and it should suggest members of the `Physics` namespace.

It might just be a matter of waiting (or restarting VS or rebuilding?) until it decides to reparse your code.